# How can I get the Name of the Program associated with a file extension using C#?

Tags: c#

How can I get the Name of the Program associated with a file extension using C#, without using Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WinApi function [AssocQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773471.aspx)

```
[DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint AssocQueryString(AssocF flags, AssocStr str,
  string pszAssoc, string pszExtra, [Out]StringBuilder pszOut, ref uint pcchOut);
```

Create enumerations [AssocF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762471.aspx) and [AssocStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762475.aspx).

```
 public enum AssocStr {
        ASSOCSTR_COMMAND = 1,
        ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,
        ASSOCSTR_FRIENDLYDOCNAME,
        ASSOCSTR_FRIENDLYAPPNAME,
        ASSOCSTR_NOOPEN,
        ASSOCSTR_SHELLNEWVALUE,
        ASSOCSTR_DDECOMMAND,
        ASSOCSTR_DDEIFEXEC,
        ASSOCSTR_DDEAPPLICATION,
        ASSOCSTR_DDETOPIC,
        ASSOCSTR_INFOTIP,
        ASSOCSTR_QUICKTIP,
        ASSOCSTR_TILEINFO,
        ASSOCSTR_CONTENTTYPE,
        ASSOCSTR_DEFAULTICON,
        ASSOCSTR_SHELLEXTENSION,
        ASSOCSTR_DROPTARGET,
        ASSOCSTR_DELEGATEEXECUTE,
        ASSOCSTR_SUPPORTED_URI_PROTOCOLS,
        ASSOCSTR_MAX
    }
    public enum AssocF
    {
        ASSOCF_NONE = 0x00000000,
        ASSOCF_INIT_NOREMAPCLSID = 0x00000001,
        ASSOCF_INIT_BYEXENAME = 0x00000002,
        ASSOCF_OPEN_BYEXENAME = 0x00000002,
        ASSOCF_INIT_DEFAULTTOSTAR = 0x00000004,
        ASSOCF_INIT_DEFAULTTOFOLDER = 0x00000008,
        ASSOCF_NOUSERSETTINGS = 0x00000010,
        ASSOCF_NOTRUNCATE = 0x00000020,
        ASSOCF_VERIFY = 0x00000040,
        ASSOCF_REMAPRUNDLL = 0x00000080,
        ASSOCF_NOFIXUPS = 0x00000100,
        ASSOCF_IGNOREBASECLASS = 0x00000200,
        ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN = 0x00000400,
        ASSOCF_INIT_FIXED_PROGID = 0x00000800,
        ASSOCF_IS_PROTOCOL = 0x00001000,
        ASSOCF_INIT_FOR_FILE = 0x00002000
    }
```

Create a helper method

```
static string AssocQueryString(AssocStr association, string extension) {
     const int S_OK = 0;
     const int S_FALSE = 1;

     uint length = 0;
     uint ret = AssocQueryString(AssocF.ASSOCF_NONE, association, extension, null, null, ref length);
     if (ret != S_FALSE) {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not determine associated string");
     }

     var sb = new StringBuilder((int)length);
     ret = AssocQueryString(AssocF.ASSOCF_NONE, association, extension, null, sb, ref length);
     if (ret != S_OK) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not determine associated string");
     }

     return sb.ToString();
```

}

You can use this way

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
           Console.WriteLine(AssocQueryString(AssocStr.ASSOCSTR_FRIENDLYAPPNAME, ".pdf"));
            Console.Read();
 }
```

Comment: The method you suggested internally queries the registry so this is not a real answer. Simple answer is: it won´t work.

Comment: Although I agree with @HimBromBeere; I do like this option.

Comment: @Stefan Well, it is a nice approch, no question. However it does not actually answer the question provided by OP.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: strangely enough OP wrote this answer.

Comment: Perhaps OP simply meant "without having to fiddle with Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey (directly)"?